# how to invite friend in facebook api to list friends

Tags: facebook, api

how to invite friend in facebook api to list friends  usign c# or Vb net or php 
I looked in the documentation but I did not thank you for helping me find

Comment: what do you mean? do you want to invite a friend to your app or do you want to request friendship between 2 users?

Comment: To invite people to an app use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Comment: I want to request friendship between 2 users

Comment: but I find applications that makes this feature exemple in http://ntweb.org/products/facebookposterandscheduler , I do not know what it is to use the API or something else

Answer (score 0):

Requesting Friendship is not possible (anymore), see docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/friends/v2.1

> This was removed as of Graph API version 2.0

It is only possible to open a dialog in v1.0, sending friend requests without a dialog is not possible even with v1.0.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/friends#readmodifiers

In short though this only works if both of the users are users of your app and you have the appropriate permissions.

The application listed in your example either does this, or it is using the old api and will have to change in the future when V1 is removed. On a side note, you shouldn't post your follow up as an answer to your own question but as a comment

Comment: but I find applications that makes this feature exemple in http://ntweb.org/products/facebookposterandscheduler , I do not know what it is to use the API or something else

Comment: As I said in my answer. They won't be able to do this going forward as it will be deprecated. You can't do it now as they've removed it for new apps and old apps will break eventually so the answer is you can't and your example site will have to change soon anyway